# How to restore function attributes to default

Tags: core-language, attributes

Adding an attribute to a function is easy and clearing attribute is easy also. But I don't know really how to restore the attributes of a function to its defaults. All I do is quit the kernel or close *Mathematica* and open again.

any idea?

#### Update

For example :

```
Log // Attributes
(* {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected} *)

ClearAttributes[Log, Listable]
Log // Attributes
(* {NumericFunction, Protected} *)
```

Now is there any way to restore the attributes of `Log` to its defaults other than `SetAttributes` or quitting *Mathematica*?

Thanks.

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, {Listable, Orderless}]; ClearAttributes[f, Attributes@f];
Attributes@f`

Comment: This clears all attributes. I am looking for something to reset attributes to default.

Comment: You don't have to quit MMA, you can just `Quit[]`, i.e.,`Quit Kernel` without having to start a new front-end session.

Comment: @kguler pity that you didn't post this as an answer :)

Comment: What I don't understand: `Log` has the attribute `Protected`. Why can we change its attributes without unprotecting it - `Unprotect[Log]` - in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have not saved the attributes before changing them, and **also** can't quit the Kernel, then you could launch a **Subkernel** and get the original attributes that way:

```
ClearAttributes[Log, Listable]

Attributes[Log]
```

> `{NumericFunction, Protected}`

```
First@ParallelEvaluate[Attributes[Log]]
```

> `{Listable,NumericFunction,Protected}`

Answer (score 15):

Save defaults before any changes

```
attrLog = Log // Attributes;

ClearAttributes[Log, Listable]

Log // Attributes
```

> {NumericFunction, Protected}

Restore defaults

```
Attributes[Log] = attrLog
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected}