# Combining many plots with Show produces wrong x-axis position and wrong filling

Tags: plotting

The code is as follows,

```
g1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis];
g2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Green, Filling -> Axis];
g3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[0] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis];
g4 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]], 
   PlotStyle -> Gray, Filling -> Axis];
g5 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[x, ArcSin[-2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, Filling -> Axis];
g6 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Brown, Filling -> Axis];
Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6}, PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

What I get is this. The x axis is not at the right position, and some filling is not to the axis. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is that the filling is generated to fit within each individual plot range. So just set the `PlotRange` in each of the plots individually, rather than just in the `Show` command. That way, the filling will fill the whole common plot range.

Comment: @MarkMcClure its `AxesOrigin` that's causing the issue. `Show` will _usually_ combine the plot ranges of the graphics, but it takes `AxesOrigin` from the first graphics object.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I think you're right.  I guess my approach fixes the problem precisely because it forces the `AxesOrgin` to be the same throughout.

Comment: @MarkMcClure absolutely. I think this is a good illustration of what `Show` manages to do by itself and what it needs some extra hints at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Show` combines multiple `Graphics` objects together, but it only works after everything has already been processed. So, it has to make some judgements on how to combine the resulting options together, and for most it uses the options present in the first `Graphics` object.  Looking at your original graphic, I suspect it is the first plot that causes the issues,

```
In[17]:= Options[g1, {PlotRange, AxesOrigin}]

Out[17]= {PlotRange -> {{-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0.536887, 0.999999}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.52}}
```

As you can see, `Plot` is setting the `PlotRange` fairly high, but the issue is the `AxesOrigin` which is causing the fill to not go to the same point as the other graphs.  To correct that, add `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` to all your plots, but it is not needed in `Show`. Then you get this,

[image]

Now time for overkill. As there are a number of options that are the same across the plots, it often pays to set them for all the plots, but if you use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) you need to remember to restore them afterwards. So, I would use a custom environment:

```
ClearAll[BlockOptions];
SetAttributes[BlockOptions, HoldAll];
BlockOptions[f : {_Symbol, ___?OptionQ | {___?OptionQ}}, body_] := 
 BlockOptions[{f}, body]
BlockOptions[f : {{_Symbol, ___?OptionQ | {___?OptionQ}} ...}, 
  body_] :=
 With[{fcns = f[[All, 1]]},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[fcns,
   SetOptions @@@ f;
   body
   ]
  ]
```

where `BlockOptions` temporarily changes the options for you. (See this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/52) for the details of `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``). Then, your code becomes

```
Show@
 BlockOptions[
  {Plot, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}},
  {
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1]], 
    PlotStyle -> Red], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[2/3]],
     PlotStyle -> Green], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[0] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1/3]], 
    PlotStyle -> Blue], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]], 
    PlotStyle -> Gray], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> 
     Function[x, ArcSin[-2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-1/3]], 
    PlotStyle -> Orange], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-2/3]],
     PlotStyle -> Brown]
   }
  ]
```

giving the same result. I used `PlotRange` here, instead of `AxesOrigin`, as it gives the same result, and I could move it out of `Show`.

Comment: how to  restore Options to default?

Comment: @Algohi I'm confused. What are you asking about? `BlockOptions` restores the options on exit.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Thank you!

Comment: @rcollyer when you set option let us say SetOptions[Plot, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], then you can plot perfectly as OP wants. now this option still there. so without kernel quit, how to reset plot options to default?

Comment: @Algohi That's what `BlockOptions` is for, to reset the options to what they were. Without it, you have to first save the options as they are. ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` does this job for us by restoring any list symbol (`Plot` in this case) to its original state on exit. Otherwise you have to use another variable. But, if you haven't done that and if you don't remember what they were, originally, you can use a [sub-kernel to reacquire](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60402/52) what they were.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to fill each `Plot` to `0` rather than `Axes` and set `AxesOrigin` to `{0, 0}` in `Show`

```
g1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1]],
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   Filling -> 0];
g2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[2/3]],
   PlotStyle -> Green,
   Filling -> 0];
g3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[0] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1/3]],
   PlotStyle -> Blue,
   Filling -> 0];
g4 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]],
   PlotStyle -> Gray,
   Filling -> 0];
g5 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[-2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-1/3]],
   PlotStyle -> Orange,
   Filling -> 0];
g6 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[x, ArcSin[-1] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-2/3]],
   PlotStyle -> Brown, Filling -> 0];
Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6},
 PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yet another approach is using a single `Plot` with `ConditionalExpression`

```
colors = {Brown, Orange, Gray, Blue, Green, Red};
Plot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[Sin @ x, #1 < Sin @ Sin @ x < #2] & @@@
             Partition[Range[-1, 1, 1/3], 2, 1]], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
     PlotStyle -> colors, BaseStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Note: For Version 9 you need to explicitly give the filling colors, by adding the option

```
FillingStyle -> (#1 -> Directive[Opacity[.5], #2] & @@@ Transpose[{Range[6], colors}])
```

or changing the `Filling` specification to

```
Filling -> ({#1 -> {Axis, Directive[Opacity[.5], #2]}} & @@@ Transpose[{Range[6], colors}])
```

Comment: Impressive how you shortened this thing :)

Comment: @eldo, it is actually longer in V9 (you need to add the filling styles explicitly); in V10  filling collors are picked nicely from `PlotStyle` colors.

Comment: I'm glad some one did this.