# Another weird plotting result

Tags: plotting

I asked a question this morning [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60451/combining-many-plots-with-show-produces-wrong-x-axis-position-and-wrong-filling), which has been resolved.

However, I got another problem. I want to add some lines to the graph, which turns out glitched. The code is as follows,

```
g1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1]], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
g2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
g3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[0] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
g4 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
g5 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[x, ArcSin[-2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
g6 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l1 = Plot[y = 1, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l2 = Plot[y = 2/3, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l3 = Plot[y = 1/3, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[0] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l4 = Plot[y = -1/3, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l5 = Plot[y = -2/3, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[x, ArcSin[-2/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-1/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
l6 = Plot[y = -3/3, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[x, ArcSin[-3/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[-2/3]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {-1, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]
The problems of this graph are marked by the black circles. It seems that the red lines are at the right position (y=1/3=0.6666...), but g2 and g5 is not precisely drawn. Take a closer look at the picture, g2 and g5 is plotted a bit longer than what they are supposed to be.

[image]

I want to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would approach this differently.  Managing so many graphs that are similar and need to be updated similarly might prove a headache.  We can take advantage of the mathematical similarities with functionality that is built into *Mathematica*.

The sort of coloring you're after can be done with [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshShading.html).  The [`Ceiling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ceiling.html) function may be used to construct a step function.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[{x, t Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1},
  MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#1] &}, Mesh -> {Range[-2, 2]/3}, 
  MeshShading -> {{Opacity[0.4], Blue}, {Opacity[0.4], Orange}}],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#1] &}, Mesh -> {Range[-2, 2]/3}, 
  MeshShading -> {Blue, Orange}],
 Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is so nice although it took me a while to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually your graphics are correct, they ARE "precisely drawn", the problem does not come from Mathematica.

You just made a little (but repeated) mathematical mistake when defining the RegionFunction parts : you have to get rid of all the ArcSin and everything will be fine.

For example in the graphic g1, instead of :

`ArcSin[-1/3] < Sin[x] < ArcSin[0]`

you should just write

`-1/3 < Sin[x] < 0`

which is more coherent you'll agree ...

Do the same for all your other graphics.