# How to eliminate the white gaps in the graph

Tags: plotting

Here is my code

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis],
 Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Floor[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, Filling -> Axis],
 AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False
 ]
```

and here is the result,

[image]
As you can see, there are white gaps in the graph, which I want to avoid. Thank you!

Comment: I have none on _v8_: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E8wV6.png Have you tried playing with `Exclusions`?

Comment: @Öskå Yes your graph looks perfect.

Comment: @Pickett I don't know why either. I am also using V10. Maybe this is a bug of V10?

Comment: It can be observered on 9.01 too but it depends of the size of the plot.

Comment: @AnnaLe Yes, I think it could be called a bug.

Comment: For me this is a longstanding *Mathematica* problem.  It appears with different types plots as they are resized and the edge positions are not rendered uniformly.  I am not aware of any general solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had almost the same problem with the original code:

[image]

Using `Exclusions` as Öskå suggested works for me. kguler pointed out that `Exclusions -> None` is the correct setting to fix this problem:

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None], 
 Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Floor[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
 AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: In version 9.0.1.0 `Exclusions->None` also works (+1)..

Comment: @kguler Thanks! This setting makes more sense to me, too.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is mainly about why there are gaps, and why it may not be a bug ( of `Graphics`).

First take a look at this example:

```
Row[
    Plot[Floor[x], {x, 1, 3}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, 
       Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}, ImageSize -> 201, 
       Exclusions -> #] & /@ {True, None}
   ];
Column[{%, % /. Polygon[pts__] :> {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Polygon[pts]}}]
```

[image: plots with and without Exclusions]

It seems an exclusion point will force `Plot` using seperate `Polygon`s, while `Exclusions -> None` makes it using a single one. That is why @Pickett 's method works.

Now take a look at the `FullForm` of the plot with gap, it can be seen that the right most points of the left `Polygon` have a x-coordinate `` 1.999362244897959` ``, which is slightly smaller than that of the left most points of the right `Polygon` `` 2.0006377551020407` ``. So I would say this is a "real" gap (possible deliberately introduced by `Exclusions -> True` to indicate the (neighbourhood of the) exclusion point) for a (most-of-the-time) good purpose.

To eliminate the gaps, one just need to align the corresponding vertices perfectly. For example:

```
With[{w = .1, δw = 0.001},
    Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{
                {0, 1}, {0, 0},
                {w, 0}, {w, 1},
                {w + δw, 1}, {w + δw, 0},
                {2 w, 0}, {2 w, 1}
                },
            {
                EdgeForm[],
                FaceForm[RGBColor[0.368417`, 0.506779`, 0.709798`]],
                Polygon[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Polygon[{{5, 6, 7, 8}}]
                }
            ]]
    ]
```

If `δw` is set to `0`, even there are still two `Polygon`s, there won't be any visible gap under any `ImageSize`. (Tested in MMA 9.0.1 and 10.0.1 on Windows 8.1.)

Now we can see the problem here: those points where gaps happen are discontinuity points of `Floor`, but they still belong to the function's domain thus should not be excluded. I would say this can be a flaw (or even a bug) of `Plot` and would be happy if there were an option say `Discontinuity -> ...`. For people who look for more details about this exclusion vs. discontinuity topic, there is [a thread on it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39462/17).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Pickett's answer using kguler's suggestion about using `Exclusions->None`, here's a way to avoid using `Show`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], 
  Sign[Sin[x]] Floor[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, LightRed}, 3 -> {Axis, LightBlue}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Instead of separately creating 3 plots of functions over the same interval and then overlaying the graphics, it creates everything using 1 plot. The advantage of this approach is that if you need to change something, you only need to change one thing, rather than 3 things, saving you effort. [Michael E2's answer to your previous question also pointed this out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60485/9697), so this is definitely a tip that you should learn, as it'll save you some headaches later, and saves quite a bit of unnecessary typing/formatting.

Answer (score 3):

To get the fine control over the graphics, I would one probably has to construct each element and combine them.  As [@Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia) points out, exclusions cause separate polygons to be created.  When rendered on a discrete screen, these may overlap or have gaps.

That means drawing the step curve and its filling separately, like this:

```
Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red],
Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Red], Exclusions -> None]
```

If you don't want to copy, paste, and edit each step function plot, you could write a function to combine both plots, such as the following:

```
SetAttributes[plotWithFilling, HoldAll];
plotWithFilling[Plot[f_, x_, opts___], col_] :=
  Show[
   Plot[f, x, PlotStyle -> col, opts],
   Plot[f, x, PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], col], Exclusions -> None, opts]];
```

Usage:

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 plotWithFilling[
  Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Ceiling[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}],
  Red
  ],
 plotWithFilling[
  Plot[Sign[Sin[x]] Floor[Abs[Sin[x]], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}],
  Green
  ],
 AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]