# Exclusions in plot not rendered correctly

Tags: plotting

I have been struggling with these glitches for two days...

A related question I asked is here
[How to eliminate the white gaps in the graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60558/how-to-eliminate-the-white-gaps-in-the-graph)

Here is the code,

```
Show[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  Plot[Ceiling[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None], 
  Plot[Floor[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Green, Exclusions -> None, Filling -> Axis], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False]
```

and here is the result,

[image]

If I remove the "Exclusions -> None" option, there are white gaps.

```
Show[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  Plot[Ceiling[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis], 
  Plot[Floor[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green , Filling -> Axis], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/Pi, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `PlotPoints -> 100` for each plot seems to fix the problem, but somehow this is not really a very satisfying approach.

Comment: in any case you *really* need to work on your MS-Paint-fu :D

Comment: You're using two user names. Please ask a moderator to merge both accounts.

Comment: Tony, please fill out this developer contact form and request a merge of your accounts.  I cannot merge them for you. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/contact  (Select **I need to merge user profiles**.)

Comment: For this particular case it seem that you can use `Exclusions -> 0` without ill effect.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that solves it! What is the difference between 0 and none?

Comment: Basically, you need at least two sample points in each step of `Ceiling`/`Floor` to be sure that recursive refinement will kick in.  The smallest step has length `ArcSin[1/3]` and the plot domain has length `4 Pi`.  So `PlotPoints -> 1 + 2 Ceiling[((2 Pi) - (-2 Pi))/ArcSin[1/3]]` will be sufficient (i.e. `PlotPoints -> 75`).  A smaller number may work if you're lucky.

Comment: @Tony `Exclusions -> 0` means put a plot exclusion at point *x = 0*.  This also causes the points around zero to be better refined in the manner that Michael describes above.  Exclusions cause the problematic gaps elsewhere, but at zero there are not any bars side-by-side to show it so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question can be much reduced to reveal the essential problem.

```
Plot[Ceiling[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: plot1]

The problem is solved by asking for more plot points.

```
Plot[Ceiling[Sin[x], 1/3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image: plot2]