# Temporarily setting built-in function options at lower levels

Tags: graphics, options, size

Slightly extending rcollyer's [handy helper](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60454/2249)
(originally `"BlockOptions"`) to `TemporarilySet` system function options via an operator form:

```
SetAttributes[TemporarilySet, HoldAll];

TemporarilySet[f : {_Symbol, ___?OptionQ | {___?OptionQ}}, body_] :=TemporarilySet[{f}, body]

TemporarilySet[f : {{_Symbol, ___?OptionQ | {___?OptionQ}} ...}, body_] :=
  With[{fcns = f[[All, 1]]}, Internal`InheritedBlock[fcns, SetOptions @@@ f;body]];

TemporarilySet[stgs_] := With[{evalStgs = stgs},
                           Function[{body}, TemporarilySet[evalStgs, body], HoldAll]];
```

we can set up an environment

```
  $PlotTheme = "Minimal";
  graphs = {Histogram, BarChart, SmoothHistogram, PieChart, ListLinePlot};
  graphEnv = {#, ImageSize -> Tiny} & /@ graphs;
```

in which certain `graphs` are `Tiny`

```
 assoc = <|"a" -> 7, b -> 8, "c" -> 9|>;
 Query[graphs]@assoc // TemporarilySet@graphEnv
```

[image]

but we might not want to be restricted to these particular graphs and since they all eventually use `Graphics` shouldn't we be able to set this at this lower level?

```
graphEnv = {Graphics, ImageSize -> Tiny};
Query[graphs]@assoc // TemporarilySet@graphEnv
```

[image]

Apparently not?

Comment: The other environment setter - `$PlotTheme` suggests expanding `TemporarilySet` to include global variables so *their* effects don't linger ... and/or have `$ImageSize` as a new global variably to get WL's function count that little higher.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why isn't the second graphic tiny as well? i.e. setting the `Graphics` option is not grabbing.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for in "why."  This is simply the inheritance/precedence model used.  Are you looking for possible reasoning behind that design decision?  Or is your interest more pragmatic?

Comment: Pragmatic, e.g. `graphEnv = {{Plot, ImageSize -> Tiny}, {Graphics, ImageSize -> Tiny}}` doesn't grab either - I want to set `ImageSize->Tiny` once, somewhere ...

Comment: I took a shot at that in an update below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25903/discussion-between-ronald-monson-and-mr-wizard).

Comment: Hope you don't mind the title change. When I saw the title I thought it was about `SystemOptions`, which I always wanted to `Block` in some way ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Sine you're here do you know why ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` appears to fail on `Cell`, meaning `SetOptions[Cell, . . .]` is not localized?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No ... I need to go now but will check back in an hour!

Comment: @Szabolics no that is a better title.

Comment: Related: [(3247)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121),  [(38827)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options (including internal defaults) for `Plot` etc. override the options set for `Graphics`.  For example:

```
SetOptions[Graphics, ImageSize -> Tiny];

Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

If you wish to use the `Graphics` setting try [`Inherited`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inherited.html):

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Inherited]
```

[image]

---

> I want to set `ImageSize->Tiny` once, somewhere ...

If you want to affect the default image size for multiple `Graphics` sources you can set it as the Box Options level:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> Tiny}]
```

Now both `Plot` and `Graphics` in this Notebook render at the Tiny size by default:

```
Graphics[Circle[]]
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

This setting can be made at the Cell, Notebook, or Global level as suits your needs.  It can also be used within [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) which I believe may be the best answer to your question:

```
withImageSize[size_] := Style[#, GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> size}] &

Query[graphs]@assoc // withImageSize[Tiny]
```

[image]

```
Query[graphs]@assoc // withImageSize[Small]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes the `Style` solution serves my immediate purposes. It does highlight however, that I was using a sledgehammer to crack a nut as the broader utility of `TemporarilySet` is not tapped into (e.g. using in-built option settings and/or doing so "per function"). As noted, there were some issues with this broader application but will cross that bridge when next seeing it.

Comment: @Ronald Thanks for the Accept.