# How to "undo" SetOptions (restore defaults)?

Tags: options, customization

Say I had some good reason to use, for example

```
SetOptions[Plot,ImageSize->500, LabelStyle->OutrageousPink];
```

But now sometime has passed, life has changed, and I changed my mind. I don't remember which options I have set for plot, let alone what their default values were. Is there a way to "undo" this?

PS: I know that I can save in advance all the options with `plotOptions=Options[Plot]`, but this requires thinking ahead, which I'm obviously trying to avoid...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore function attributes to default](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60382/how-to-restore-function-attributes-to-default)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw this somewhere else on here, but I cannot remember where. The simplest method is to use a fresh kernel:

```
SetOptions[Plot, Axes -> False];
LaunchKernels[1];
ParallelEvaluate[Options[Plot, Axes]]
(* {{Axes -> True}} *)
```

then you dispose of the kernel

```
CloseKernels[]
(* {KernelObject[1, "local", "<defunct>"]} *)
```

Comment: Something like this was used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60382/245), although that was about `Attributes`, and not `Options`... (+1)

Comment: @Jens yes, that is exactly where I remember seeing it.

Comment: @rcollyer Probably instead of `AbortKernels[]` you meant `CloseKernels[]`...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov why yes I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`LocalSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSubmit). Here's a function to do this:

```
originalOptions[sym_, option_] := Module[{res},
    TaskWait @ LocalSubmit[
        Options[sym, option], 
        HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> ((res = #["EvaluationResult"])&)|>
    ];
    res
]
```

Then:

```
SetOptions[Plot, Axes->False];
originalOptions[Plot, Axes]
```

> {Axes -> True}

Comment: which, of course, is a self-contained method of sending it to a parallel kernel. :)