# Quickly restoring default notebook display color and font

Tags: notebooks, customization, stylesheet

(Not a duplicate. I've checked [How to "undo" SetOptions (restore defaults)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67062/how-to-undo-setoptions-restore-defaults) and others.)

Suppose I change some display options, e.g.:

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> RGBColor[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 FontColor -> RGBColor[0, .85, .85], FontSize -> 20]`

Is there a way to restore all the default display options at once, in a line or two of code, without rebooting the notebook or digging through the menus? Something like `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Defaults]` or a similar idea? I haven't been able to find what I need in other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> Inherited, FontColor -> Inherited, 
 FontSize -> Inherited]
```

works in your case. Basically, when working with FrontEnd options `Inherited` is what you mean by "Default". But it doesn't always work through `SetOptions`, `CurrentValue` usually is a better choice.

---

**Update.** For `"UndefinedSymbolStyle"` discussed in the comments two solutions were found working:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], AutoStyleOptions -> {"UndefinedSymbolStyle" -> Inherited}]

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, "UndefinedSymbolStyle"}] = Inherited
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! Follow-up question: I had used `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, 
   "UndefinedSymbolStyle"}] = {FontColor -> 
   RGBColor[0.5, 0.173, 0.765]}` to edit the color of variable names to fit within the high-contrast color theme, but when I try to set `FontColor -> Inherited` then everything turns black (instead of the default variable color of blue). Do you know how to fix that, or should I post as a separate question? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @icthyophile `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"UndefinedSymbolStyle" -> Inherited}]` works. Please report the problem to the tech support (support(at)wolfram.com), I strongly suspect that we have a bug in `CurrentValue` for `CurrentValue[
  EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, "UndefinedSymbolStyle", FontColor}] = Inherited` (it is the correct usage).

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Your first solution worked great. I also tried `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {AutoStyleOptions, 
   "UndefinedSymbolStyle"}] = Inherited` and it worked. You solved what a half-hour of my searching couldn't figure out. Thanks for your help!