# Reset Options to Default

Tags: options

It is straightforward to set the options of a given predefined function. E.g.,

```
SetOptions[ Interpolation, InterpolationOrder->1]
```

I would like to know if there is a similar way to reset the options to default.

I thought of the following possible solution, but it closes the Mathematica session in Linux terminal before reaching the line `<<state.mx`. The latter would restore all the user-defined variables and functions.

```
DumpSave["state.mx", "Global`"]
Quit[]
<<state.mx
```

A similar question concerning `Attributes` has been asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60382/how-to-restore-function-attributes-to-default), what does not seem to help me.

Comment: "A similar question concerning Attributes has been asked here, what does not seem to help me." <-- Why not?

Comment: I do not want to clear `Attributes`, but `Options`.

Comment: The same idea applies.  You can get the default options form a subkernel and set them (`Options[sym] = ...`).

Comment: I was going to post an answer based on that, but I have doubts whether this case is generally considered as a duplicate. Or if it is okay to have different questions with a similar solution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one.